# How can be detected packet loss GStreamer - webrtcbin (and how to send PLI or FIR then)

Tags: browser, webrtc, gstreamer

I'm developing GStreamer based application for receiving WebRTC stream from browser.
I've just started with example of webrtc-sendrecv.c:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-examples/-/tree/master/webrtc/sendrecv/gst

Problem is broken image. Source is screen share (getDisplayMedia) - after some time of transmission i get different color squares - something is missing even on one PC or LAN.

Tried browser on Linux and MacOS and GStreamer application on two linux distribution (gstreamer 1.16.2 and 1.18.0)

Now I don't know how can be this detected and how can be send PLI or FIR messages to source browser.

Do you please know how to face this? And if so, how?
Thanks, d3im

EDIT1:
OK, I see significant packets loss after some time of running in vivaldi://webrtc-internals
There must be something wrong in example app.

I can get on browser side how many packets are lost:

```js
function getStats(pc) {
    if (pc) {
        pc.getStats(null).then(stats => {
            stats.forEach(report => {
              if ( (report.type=="remote-inbound-rtp") && (report.kind=="video") ) {
                console.log(report.packetsLost);
              }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

What is the way to tell browser PLI? Is there some API call for that in JS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome, to get an idea about about the amount of packet loss, you can check the WebRTC statistics by visiting chrome://webrtc-internals. It will show you lots of statistics about the actual RTCPeerConnection, including packet loss and round-trip time.